# Remove dynamically added item from map function with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently, i have started to learn React.js and have been trying to understand its gotchas.

Wanted to build a very simple to-do.

I can simply add to-do's but when it come to check and remove it, i am having problems.

I am using this function to remove a to-do element from my map function:

**

```
removeItem: function(e) {
            var index = this.state.items.indexOf(e.target.value)
            this.state.items.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState({
              items: this.state.items
            });
          },
```

**

**When you try to remove middle element, it removes another one.Why?**

**Also how can i toggle className?**

```
checkItem: function(e) {
   this.refs.theItem.className = 'checked';
  },
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t9uLn4hm/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change:

`this.state.items.splice(index, 1);`

With:

`this.state.items.splice((index-1), 1);`

Since the index starts from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Indexes in JS start at zero, not one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `e.target.value` is `undefined`, so then you try to find the index of `undefined` in `this.state.items`. Since it’s not there, `indexOf` returns `-1`. Passing `-1` to `splice` tells it to remove the *last* item from the list.

You will have to change it so `removeItem` receives the proper information, probably by changing the `onClick` to pass the index explicitly, e.g. `(event) => this.removeItem(index, event)` or similar.